# DataFrame.loc() on MultiIndex doesn't work?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large DataFrame with a MultiIndex: Date and Stock. The DataFrame have many columns. Name the DataFrame `features`. Notice that the index has been sorted (I assume first by Date then by Stock).

```
features.sort_index(inplace=True)
features
```

[image]

---

Now I want to get a slice of the DataFrame where all Date are within a time range. But apparently I'm doing something wrong and the result still contain Date outside the range.

```
df2 = features.copy()
df2.loc[pd.IndexSlice[pd.IndexSlice[pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01'):pd.Timestamp('2015-12-31'), :], :]]
```

[image]

---

Note that, strangely, if I remove most of the columns, the same `.loc` call successfully removes the rows w/ dates outside the time range.

```
df = features.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'AAPL'], :]
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[pd.IndexSlice[pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01'):pd.Timestamp('2015-12-31'), :], :]]
```

[image]

---

Question: am I doing anything wrong, or is it a bug?

p.s.:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.5.2

$ python -c "import pandas as pd; print(pd.__version__)"
0.18.1
```

**EDIT:**

It may have been a bug in pandas 0.18.1. The reason I'm saying this is that the problem went away after I upgrade to 0.19.2 (by `pip install --upgrade pandas`).

Another possibility is that my ipython notebook needs a restart. However, I did try to restart the kernel and rerun the above code a few times before asking this question, so I tend to believe that this is not the reason.

Comment: So images are not very useful because they can not be copy and pasted.  For best response it is important to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that includes code and data that can be copy and pasted into an editor. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @StephenRauch Hi, thank you for your comment and suggestion. I agree. Though I have difficulty realizing how I can upload the big DataFrame. I suppose I can pickle it into a file, but how/where do I upload this .pkl file so ppl can try it out? I have added the python code so that ppl can see better.

Comment: The main point of an MCVE is try and boil the problem down a bit.  Failing that (which seems to be the case here), pastebin is recommended.  Oh, and not pickle, they are a security risk.  It needs to be text of some sort.

Comment: @StephenRauch Yeah I see the point of MCVE. I tried to debug a little bit above as you can see. I also tried to make up a tiny example but failed to repro the problem. So I think it's specific to the current setting of my DataFrame (i.e. something inside it) but couldn't dig deeper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my edit to the OP mentions, the problem went away after I upgrade to 0.19.2 (by pip install --upgrade pandas). For this reason, I tend to believe that it may have been a bug in pandas 0.18.1.

I will post this answer to close my own question, but if anyone who still have 0.18.1 feels that I'm wrong here, please contact me and we can dig deeper (probably by me sharing the DataFrame to you and you try to repro on 0.18.1).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [pd.to_datetime(['2014-12-15', '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31']),
     ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'CVX', 'GE', 'F']],
    names=['Date', 'Ticker']
)

# special note of the `sort_index`
# this is necessary for using `pd.IndexSlice
df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(len(mux))), mux).sort_index()

                    0
Date       Ticker    
2014-12-15 AAPL     0
           AMZN     1
           CVX      2
           F        4
           GE       3
2015-01-01 AAPL     5
           AMZN     6
           CVX      7
           F        9
           GE       8
2015-12-31 AAPL    10
           AMZN    11
           CVX     12
           F       14
           GE      13
```

---

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01'):pd.Timestamp('2015-12-31'), :], :]
# equivalent to
# df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['2015-01-01':'2015-12-31', :], :]

                    0
Date       Ticker    
2015-01-01 AAPL     5
           AMZN     6
           CVX      7
           F        9
           GE       8
2015-12-31 AAPL    10
           AMZN    11
           CVX     12
           F       14
           GE      13
```

This works just fine.  You are using nested `pd.IndexSlice` which is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'd like to make two points: (1) proving that non-nested IndexSlice works doesn't prove nested IndexSlice wrong, (2) I tried the non-nested version before creating the question and it didn't work, either, so I tend to think it's because of the 0.18.1 version.